# How can I get the YouTube Data API to return more than 20 pages of list results?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I have a pretty large liked videos playlist (~2500 videos) that I'm attempting to grab all music category videos from. As such, I've created a loop structure to grab the `nextPageToken` from the last request and use it as the `pageToken` for the current request. However, it's cutting me off when I reach 1000 total results, or 20 requests. I looked at previous questions, and they all said to split the requests into several ranges, but this already uses several ranges, the API just doesn't include the `nextPageToken` in the 20th request, thus ending my loop (and my ability to get any more page tokens). How can I get the back 2/3 of my list? Here is my code:

```py
ids_list = []
first = True
while True:
# Request the next page of the liked videos list
    if first:
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part='snippet,id',
            myRating='like',
            maxResults='50'
        )
        first = False
    else:
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part='snippet,id',
            myRating='like',
            maxResults='50',
            pageToken=next_page
        )
    response = request.execute()
        
    # Add all the music vids from this page into ids_list
    for video in response['items']:
        if video['snippet']['categoryId'] == '10':
            ids_list.append(video['id'])
                    
                    
    i += 1      
    # Continue down the pages until there are no more next pages
    if 'nextPageToken' in response:
        next_page = response['nextPageToken']
    else:
        break
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a time.sleep to slow your requests down? You could be getting rate limited.

Comment: @dir yes, I added `time.sleep(3)` right above my i incrementation. No change, that ran and stopped at 20 requests while I was writing the question sadly.

Comment: might be worth trying an absurdly large time sleep increment just to be 100% certain. Also randomising the value is always a good move to look more "human".

Comment: @dir It's the same API client session each time so I doubt that the time value helps, I hypothesize one way to get around it may be to rebuild the client after say 19 next-page queries and pick up where the previous session left off (reauthorizing required, which is why I haven't implemented it yet), but I was looking for other solutions before I resort to trying that.

Comment: @OCDkirby have you found a more practical solution?

Comment: @KevinEldurson that was unfortunately the solution. I use Google's api functions to cache an authorization token as text and end my connection after 20 queries, then create a new connection from the cached authorization and continue. My only limit is now the quota for YouTube API requests.

Comment: @OCDkirby I tried manually entering the last nextPageToken (because my last API call returns only prevPageToken) but I still can't get past 1000 videos, it still ends after that. In my case the limitation seems to be 1000 videos, not the 20 queries.
I found this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392866/7257264 however this one misses a crucial part for me (categoryId), since I use this API specifically for category 10 (music).